# How to bind mounted persistent volumes on docker ? I'm trying to run Sonarqube on docker

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I want to run SonarQube on docker. When I run the whiteout volume persist option, it works properly with this command:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube
```

But when I try to set bind-mounted persistent volumes, my docker doesn't start. The docker command used is:

```
 docker run -d --name sonarqube \
-p 9000:9000 \
-v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
-v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
-v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \
-v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
sonarqube
```

Note: I run docker command with root privilege.

I use this SonarQube image from Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube?tab=description

I get this Error in docker logs :

> >
>   06:42:37.293 [main] WARN org.sonar.application.config.AppSettingsLoaderImpl - Configuration file not found: /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
>   2019.07.07 06:42:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
>   2019.07.07 06:42:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
>   2019.07.07 06:42:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
>   2019.07.07 06:42:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
>   2019.07.07 06:42:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>   2019.07.07 06:42:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
>
> > 2019-07-07 06:42:41,143 main ERROR Unable to create file /opt/sonarqube/logs/es.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
> >         at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
> >         at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1024)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:628)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:608)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:234)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:127)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:302)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
> >
> > 2019-07-07 06:42:41,148 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5dcd8c7a] unable to create manager for [/opt/sonarqube/logs/es.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@2250b9f2[pattern=/opt/sonarqube/logs/es.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level es[][%logger{1.}] %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5dcd8c7a] unable to create manager for [/opt/sonarqube/logs/es.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@2250b9f2[pattern=/opt/sonarqube/logs/es.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, useMax=false), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level es[][%logger{1.}] %msg%n, filePermissions=null, fileOwner=null]]
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:115)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
> >         at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:234)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:127)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:302)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
> >         at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>
> 2019-07-07 06:42:41,152 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:235)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:234)
>       at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:127)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:302)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
>       at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>       at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>       at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
>       at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>
> > 2019-07-07 06:42:41,154 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
> >     2019-07-07 06:42:41,154 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "file_es" for logger config "root"
> >     2019.07.07 06:42:41 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
> >     2019.07.07 06:42:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
> >     2019.07.07 06:42:41 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

Comment: Does this file `/opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/conf/sonar.properties` exists on your host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have persistented the volumes but there is no file and required permissions. Follow below steps.

#### Start the container without persistent volume

```
$ docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 sonarqube
$ docker ps -f name=sonarqube
```

Note down the container id.

#### Copy folders from the container to host directory

```
$ cd /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube
$ chown -R 999:999 .
$ docker cp -a CONTAINER_ID:/opt/sonarqube/conf .
$ docker cp -a CONTAINER_ID:/opt/sonarqube/logs . # this can be skipped is not required 
$ docker cp -a CONTAINER_ID:/opt/sonarqube/data . # optional, if you need the existing data from the container 
$ docker cp -a CONTAINER_ID:/opt/sonarqube/extensions .
```

#### Now start the container with persistent volumes

```
$ docker run -d --name sonarqube \
       -p 9000:9000 \
       -v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf \
       -v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/data:/opt/sonarqube/data \
       -v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs \
       -v /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
       sonarqube
```

Comment: It worked by your Instruction. but whiteout  /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/data. when I added /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/data i got new Error:

Comment: Error: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Comment: This looks like a warning. Can you please post the entire error message?

Comment: Looks like error is due to postgres. Try running `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` on the host machine. Else, disable postgres in the configuration file. If you want db, then switch the image to `sonarqube:7.7-community`

Comment: I tried before sonarqube:7.7-community had same problem.

Comment: Did you try `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` on the host, restart docker, then start the container?

Comment: If you have any data in the host folder remove it and try. `rm -rf /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube/data/*`

Comment: I removed all things in data, doesn't start again. In docker log :(Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running) (no modules loaded). finally SonarQube is stopped

Comment: Try `chown -R 999:999 /opt/docker-mounts/sonaarqube`.

Comment: IT workkkkkkkkkkk. thank you indeeeeed. YOU ARE ONE.

Comment: when I go in OPR environment i get error again my new environment OS is oracle linux that docker group is 993. I change chown to 993 but docker doesn't start again. in docker logs  show me privius error :(Waiting for Elasticsearch to be

Comment: Group ID 999 is within the container only. So it will be always 999 only. Don't change that, until you change the sonarqube docker image.